# Finding the cumulative return in R

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table as follows -

```
dt <- structure(list(date = structure(c(18415L, 18416L, 18417L, 18418L, 
                                  18421L, 18422L, 18423L, 18424L, 18425L, 18428L, 18429L, 18430L, 
                                  18431L, 18432L, 18435L, 18436L, 18437L, 18438L, 18439L, 18442L, 
                                  18443L, 18444L, 18445L, 18449L, 18450L, 18451L, 18452L, 18453L, 
                                  18456L, 18457L, 18458L, 18459L, 18460L, 18463L, 18464L, 18465L, 
                                  18466L, 18467L, 18470L, 18471L, 18472L, 18473L, 18474L, 18477L, 
                                  18478L, 18479L, 18480L, 18481L, 18484L, 18485L, 18486L, 18487L, 
                                  18491L, 18493L, 18494L, 18495L, 18498L, 18499L, 18500L, 18501L, 
                                  18502L, 18505L), class = c("IDate", "Date")), 
               close = c(12.11, 
                         11.26, 10.8, 10.335, 10.55, 10.73, 10.74, 10.27, 10.36, 10.59, 
                         10.72, 10.2, 10.22, 9.94, 9.92, 9.71, 10.13, 10.81, 10.87, 11.06, 
                         11.63, 11.245, 12.02, 12.62, 12.97, 13.37, 13.85, 13.425, 13.97, 
                         14.01, 14.7, 14.72, 16.15, 16.49, 16.93, 17.05, 16.85, 16.5, 
                         17.7, 17.24, 17.495, 18.73, 18.15, 19.15, 19.29, 19.58, 13.09, 
                         14.05, 14.55, 13.41, 13.79, 13.44, 13.58, 13.15, 13.19, 14.785, 
                         14.415, 15.085, 14.41, 11.53, 11.69, 11.72), 
               group = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                            1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                            0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)), 
          row.names = c(NA, -62L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

It looks like follows -

```
         date  close group
 1: 2020-06-02 12.110     0
 2: 2020-06-03 11.260     0
 3: 2020-06-04 10.800     0
 4: 2020-06-05 10.335     0
 5: 2020-06-08 10.550     0
 6: 2020-06-09 10.730     0
 7: 2020-06-10 10.740     0
 8: 2020-06-11 10.270     0
 9: 2020-06-12 10.360     0
10: 2020-06-15 10.590     1
11: 2020-06-16 10.720     1
12: 2020-06-17 10.200     1
13: 2020-06-18 10.220     0
14: 2020-06-19  9.940     0
15: 2020-06-22  9.920     1
16: 2020-06-23  9.710     0
17: 2020-06-24 10.130     1
18: 2020-06-25 10.810     1
19: 2020-06-26 10.870     1
20: 2020-06-29 11.060     1
21: 2020-06-30 11.630     1
22: 2020-07-01 11.245     1
23: 2020-07-02 12.020     1
24: 2020-07-06 12.620     1
25: 2020-07-07 12.970     1
26: 2020-07-08 13.370     1
27: 2020-07-09 13.850     1
28: 2020-07-10 13.425     1
29: 2020-07-13 13.970     1
30: 2020-07-14 14.010     1
31: 2020-07-15 14.700     1
32: 2020-07-16 14.720     1
33: 2020-07-17 16.150     1
34: 2020-07-20 16.490     1
35: 2020-07-21 16.930     1
36: 2020-07-22 17.050     1
37: 2020-07-23 16.850     1
38: 2020-07-24 16.500     1
39: 2020-07-27 17.700     1
40: 2020-07-28 17.240     0
41: 2020-07-29 17.495     0
42: 2020-07-30 18.730     0
43: 2020-07-31 18.150     0
44: 2020-08-03 19.150     0
45: 2020-08-04 19.290     1
46: 2020-08-05 19.580     0
47: 2020-08-06 13.090     0
48: 2020-08-07 14.050     0
49: 2020-08-10 14.550     0
50: 2020-08-11 13.410     0
51: 2020-08-12 13.790     0
52: 2020-08-13 13.440     0
53: 2020-08-17 13.580     0
54: 2020-08-19 13.150     1
55: 2020-08-20 13.190     0
56: 2020-08-21 14.785     1
57: 2020-08-24 14.415     1
58: 2020-08-25 15.085     1
59: 2020-08-26 14.410     1
60: 2020-08-27 11.530     0
61: 2020-08-28 11.690     0
62: 2020-08-31 11.720     0
          date  close group
```

Column `close` is the closing price of a stock and column `group` is the buy-sell decision. If the value of the `group` is `1`, then it's a buy decision else it's a sell decision.

I need to add a new column to this data.table which will show the cumulative return for each `group` at any given time.

The cumulative return is the total change in the investment price over a set time — an aggregate return.

Is there any existing function in R to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Most of the users in this community are not securities analysts. Please define what you mean by "show the cumulative return for each group at a given time", preferably with expected output.

Comment: Thanks, Ian for pointing it out. I have added the definition of cumulative return. I am working to add the expected result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you're looking for?

```
dt[,.(start = head(date,1),
      end = tail(date,1),
      change = tail(close,1)-head(close,1)),
   by = rleid(group)]
    rleid      start        end change
 1:     1 2020-06-02 2020-06-12 -1.750
 2:     2 2020-06-15 2020-06-17 -0.390
 3:     3 2020-06-18 2020-06-19 -0.280
 4:     4 2020-06-22 2020-06-22  0.000
 5:     5 2020-06-23 2020-06-23  0.000
 6:     6 2020-06-24 2020-07-27  7.570
 7:     7 2020-07-28 2020-08-03  1.910
 8:     8 2020-08-04 2020-08-04  0.000
 9:     9 2020-08-05 2020-08-17 -6.000
10:    10 2020-08-19 2020-08-19  0.000
11:    11 2020-08-20 2020-08-20  0.000
12:    12 2020-08-21 2020-08-26 -0.375
13:    13 2020-08-27 2020-08-31  0.190
```

The data.table `head` and `tail` methods are very efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
dt %>% 
  group_by(grp = with(rle(group), rep(seq_along(values), lengths))) %>% 
  summarise(start = first(date), end = last(date),
            change = last(close) - first(close), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 13 x 4
#     grp start      end        change
#   <int> <date>     <date>      <dbl>
# 1     1 2020-06-02 2020-06-12 -1.75 
# 2     2 2020-06-15 2020-06-17 -0.39 
# 3     3 2020-06-18 2020-06-19 -0.28 
# 4     4 2020-06-22 2020-06-22  0    
# 5     5 2020-06-23 2020-06-23  0    
# 6     6 2020-06-24 2020-07-27  7.57 
# 7     7 2020-07-28 2020-08-03  1.91 
# 8     8 2020-08-04 2020-08-04  0    
# 9     9 2020-08-05 2020-08-17 -6.00 
#10    10 2020-08-19 2020-08-19  0    
#11    11 2020-08-20 2020-08-20  0    
#12    12 2020-08-21 2020-08-26 -0.375
#13    13 2020-08-27 2020-08-31  0.19
```